# Are there explanations for the thesis that life seems to pass by faster when you're older?

Tags: cognitive-psychology

The question is that of the title, but I came up with it with respect to a specific model so I'll state a more concrete variant of it as well:

There are theories like the one presented in Daniel Dennetts book [*Consciousness Explained*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consciousness_explained), which say that the individual acts as agent in the world, the brain is running like a machine, and while the individual principally does what he does no matter what, the conscious experience is merely a part of the brain activity on which (though some process) it decides to put emphasis on.

Can this point of view explain the common idea that life passes on faster as we get older? In the way that as the agent encounters more and more daily routines, there are just fewer and fewer things which get experienced consciously and so people are actually "less there" when their live are "more boring".